# How to receive the current depth in RecursiveASTVisitor (clang)?

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, clang++

I try to understand several weeks the principles of operation with clang
AST, but meanwhile I did not answer the main issue: how to walk on this
tree?
I read all guides which I found, studied doxygen documentation and even
watched couple of lectures on YouTube, however the understanding did not
come.

That I understood:

1) AST of a tree has no general type of nodes

2) For movement on a tree it is offered to use either RecursiveASTVisitor,
or matcher. The first recursively realizes bypass in depth, and the second
allows to look for those nodes which are interesting.

The problem is in what part of a tree I am in what in one of two options I
cannot learn. I do not know how to define at what moment my visitor passed
to other branch and at what moment continues to move to depth.
Ideally it would be desirable to know depth of the node visited by me. It is
possible?

I very much like a dump() function output because in it communications
between nodes are accurately shown. However how to receive it in pure form
(but not as the text) I do not know.

Generally, the question is as follows: whether I can construct the tree on
the basis of AST, but with uniform type of nodes and how to make it?